# PHP. Use of methods in the base class which will be defined in the derived

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Is it a good practice to use in the base class a method which will be defined in a derived one? For instance:

```
abstract class CApplication {
    use TSingleton;

    protected final function singletonInstanceInit() {
        if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
            $this->initCLIApp();
    }
        else {
            $this->initWebApp();
        }
    }
}

abstract class CWebApplication extends CApplication {   
      protected function initWebApp() { }
}

abstract class CCLIApplication extends CApplication {
    protected function initCLIApp() { }
}
```

Comment: You should define them as abstract functions in the base class.

Comment: In what scenario you have to do this ? and cant avoid

Comment: you can call them statically like CWebApplication::initWebApp() but you have to make sure the class file is included , and I do not suggest to go this way it can be just work around

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not a good practice.

Inheritance is needed for the purpose of defining new behaviors and new specialized types of objects. Which means that you *could*/*should* write a base class now and extend it some time late on.

If the base class knows something about the structure of it's derived classes that's somewhat of a contract, the derived classes *need* to implement some functions in order to work with that base class in which case "design by contract" springs to mind.

If you need to have a certain function in the derived class maybe it should be declared as an `abstract` function in the base class or as a method in an interface the class implements.

That way it's not unreasonable for the base class to *know* about methods implemented in the derived classes.

Also AFAIK other stricter languages would not permit this at compiler level. You would really need to do some refactoring to achieve this in `c++` or `Java` something along the lines of what I said above using abstract functions in the base class or interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is 2 different schools of thought. I've seen ruby developers doing such stuff because they were using mixins (yes lots of gems do that). On other hand if you go and ask a classic Java programmer he won't recommend you doing that. The type of liberty that you are just showing in your code is what only dynamic typed languages give you (Ya I know some heads would nod saying I used CGLib), they are implementable either in a hackish way for static typed languages or they are not used at all.

Long story cut short, if I were you I would look into scenario and decide if I need such **black magic** for my given task or not? No rule is bad as long as it doesn't hurt the code quality.